# Await multiple goroutine responses

Tags: go

Being new to Go I am struggling a bit with syncing the responses of multiple go routines, so that I can process the results.

**Use case**

I want to issue 4 requests with different parameters concurrently. Each response consists of multiple parts. Once all of the requests have been returned they shall be put into an array.

**Code**

```
// Create requests and process them concurrently
responseChannel := make(chan<- response, 100)
for brokerID, request := range requestsByBrokerID {
    broker := e.BrokersByBrokerID[brokerID]
    go getBrokersPartitionOffsets(broker, request, topicPartitionChannel)
}

func getBrokersPartitionOffsets(broker *sarama.Broker, request *sarama.OffsetRequest, ch chan<- partitionTopicHighWaterMark) {
    response, err := broker.GetAvailableOffsets(request)
    if err != nil {
        broker.Close()
        log.Warnf("Cannot fetch offsets from broker %v: %v", broker.ID(), err)
        return
    }

    for topic, partitions := range response.Blocks {
        for partitionID, offsetResponse := range partitions {
            if offsetResponse.Err != sarama.ErrNoError {
                // Shortned...
            }
            ch <- partitionTopicHighWaterMark{TopicName: topic, PartitionID: partitionID, HighWaterMark: offsetResponse.Offsets[0]}
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem**

I want to await until all the goroutines (started in the for loop) have finished. I read that I can close the channel, but I think this doesn't help me here because I have multiple goroutines using the same channel. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: While not a direct duplicate, the answer there solves your exact question (using `sync.WaitGroup`)

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup